# DataGridTemplateColumn Two way binding is not working

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn, two-way-binding

I've got a `DataGrid` I've bound to a `SqlDataApter`. If I set up the XAML for the grid using `DataTextColumn` as illustrated in the code below it works perfectly

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,42,0,0"
          Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KEY}" Visibility="Hidden"
                            IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CHARACTERISTIC_CODE}"
                            Header="Unit" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UNIT_CHAR}"
                            Header="Unit" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IC_DEF_CHAR_NUMERIC}"
                            Header="Number" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IC_DEF_CHAR_TEXT}"
                            Header="Text" IsReadOnly="False" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IsNumeric}"
                            Header="Status" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IsText}"
                            Header="Status" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I am binding this to a `DataTable` in code using:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dTable.DefaultView
```

And I have a button that saves the changes using the ذSqlDataAdapterذ update method:

```
dAdapter.Update(dTable)
```

The problem is that I want to disable editing the `IC_DEF_CHAR_TEXT` field when the record `isNumeri`c and the `IC_DEF_CHAR_TEXT` when the record `IsText`. I tried binding to the `IsReadOnly` property but found that it is not bind-able, so I created templates for the two fields and bound the `IsEnabled` property to the `IsText` and `IsNumeric` fields.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="27,42,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          AreRowDetailsFrozen="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KEY}" Visibility="Hidden"
                            IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CHARACTERISTIC_CODE}"
                            Header="Unit" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UNIT_CHAR}"
                            Header="Unit" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Numeric">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=IC_DEF_CHAR_NUMERIC,
                             Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox IsReadOnly="False"
                             Text="{Binding Path=IC_DEF_CHAR_NUMERIC,
                             Mode=TwoWay,
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Text" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=IC_DEF_CHAR_TEXT,
                             Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=IC_DEF_CHAR_TEXT,
                             Mode=TwoWay,
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This worked exactly like I wanted,  the textboxes were enabled when necessary. However the changes made in the `TextBoxes` are no longer saved to the database during update.  Can someone out there explain to me why the database is no longer being updated?

Comment: Try changing the `CellTemplate` to not use two-way binding as it's essentially only supposed to act as a window.

Comment: I originally set it up that way and that didn't work either.  I think two way is the default but I'm not 100% sure of that.

Comment: What I mean is that `TextBox` will default to `Two-Way`, try changing it to `One-Way` on the `CellTemplate`. You only want `Two-Way` on `CellEditingTemplate`

Comment: I just tried that and that didn't help either.  Thanks for trying

Comment: What do you mean when you say _I tried binding to the IsReadOnly property but found that it is not bindable_? You should be able to bind to this. What happened when you did?

Comment: Basically it did not do anything if I tried to bind it to a boolean field.  I could set it true or false but when I tried to bind it it was always editable.  I would like to find out why the twoway binding is not working on the textbox as I can see me having to use templates in my coding quite often.

Comment: I didn't even have to read the question content, just the topic, and the answer was exactly what I was looking for. Guess that really is just a very stupid default behavior of `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 79):

I had the same problem, not updating the source:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Obs" IsReadOnly="False">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <TextBox Name="txtObs" Width="80"
                  Text="{Binding Path=ObsPedido, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

For me it worked just adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

```
<TextBox Name="txtObs" Width="80"
         Text="{Binding Path=ObsPedido, Mode=TwoWay,
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: I had the same problem and setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` solved it. I guess this should be marked as answer.

Comment: This solved my problem too. This is a bug with only DataGrid,  I think. 2 way binding works as expected with normal fields outside DataGrid.

Comment: Had the same issue and this solved it for me as well! :-) Thank you.

Comment: Oh my God! I was searching for this solution about 2 hours! I've even started to looking on implementing "TrueObservableCollection", but I've finally found this! Thanks!

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` also works, in case you don't want to update on every key press.

Comment: I wish it could help me but I project text input into double variable, replacing invalid input with default value. So as soon as user edits text to a not-a-number (like placing decimal point after a digit or erasing the field) it's replaced with default value. So I still have to find solution not involving UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solution posted by @jrivam did not help. For me to get my binding to work correctly I had to change the `CellEditingTemplate` to use the `OneWayToSource` Binding Mode.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=IC_DEF_CHAR_TEXT,
                 Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```